# How to use triclustering in binary matrices, by the intersection of results

Tags: python, matrix, binary, set, cluster-analysis

Having an N number of binary matrices, I want to get the all the biclusters possibles for each matrix and then the tricluster result would be the intersections of the results of the biclusters found. This will after permit to filter the lenght of the sets to get the results desired.

As an example I'm trying to use this as input:

```
matrix1 = np.array([
    [1, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 1]])


matrix3 = np.array([
    [1, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0]])
```

for this the result should be something like

```
result_tricluster = [((0,0)), ((0,2)), ((1,1)), ((2,0)), ((0,0),(0,2)), ((0,0), (1,1)), ((0,0),(2,0)), ((0,2), (1,1)), ((0,2), (2,0)), ((1,1),(2,0)), ((0,0),(0,2),(1,1)), ((0,0),(0,2),(2,0)), ((0,2),(1,1),(2,0)), ((0,2),(1,1),(2,0)), ((0,0),(0,2),(1,1),(2,0))]
```

where each element is represent with their index like (row, column) and a bicluster is a tuple with the indexes.